# Which Api I Have Use To Get Item Dimensions And Ship From Address from ebay order

Tags: php, laravel, ebay-api

Hello I have some confusions regarding to identify which api need to use to get item dimensions and ship from address for eBay order.

I use following eBay API PHP SDK to get order.

https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples

I use following method to get orders from ebay

```
public function getUserToken($grand_code){
    $service = //above

    $grand_code = urldecode(urldecode($grand_code));

    $response = $service->getUserToken(new GetUserTokenRestRequest([
        'code' => $grand_code
    ]));

    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {

        $data['status'] = $response->error;
        $data['msg'] = $response->error_description;

    } else {
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['access_token'] = $response->access_token;
        $data['refresh_token'] = $response->refresh_token;
    }
    return $data;
}
```